# Не устанавливается Windows 10/11 без интернета

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

Купил ноутбук. На сайте производителя есть драйвера только под windows 10/11. После установки винды экран зависает на данных окнах при подключении к серверу Майкрософт.
Я перепробовал уже наверное с 20 сборок. И старые сборки win10 и новые, и оригинальный образы и кастомные сборки с торрентов где вырезан всякий хлам.
Так же пробовал windows11, то же самое.
Устанавливаю с флешки, во флешке проблем нет, пробовал разные флешки. На флешку пробовал писать через rufus и ultraISO, сути не меняет.
Это всё при том что у меня ноутбук отключен от интернета. Но как видно на скринах, после установки нет кнопки чтобы пропустить подключение к Майкрософт.
Я так же пробовал с подключенным интернетом, оно подключается к серверу, и потом просит меня залогинится от имени организации. Какой бы я эмейл не вводил, или не пытался зарегаться, оно каждый раз говорит что такого эмейла нет в организации.
Я пересмотрел кучу видосов и перегуглил инфы. Такие проблемы встречались в некоторых людей, но решения я не нашел.
В итоге зависает на этом состоянии. Нельзя вернуться назад, нельзя нажать пропустить, после перезагрузки то же самое окно.

[image: Проверка соединения с корпорацией Майкрософт]
[image: Кажется произошла ошибка]

Comment: Может, на вашем ноутбуке уже установлена система, а вы не ставите "с нуля", а всего лишь repair-mode запускаете? Или clean install? Вы бы детали бы указали, как ставите.

Comment: Я вставляю флешку с записанной виндой, загружаюсь с флешки, доходит до выбора раздела, я каждый раз форматирую разделы, иногда удаляю разделы потом создаю заново (думал поможет но нет), выбираю раздел для установки системы, жду окончания установки. Потом запускается установленная система уже из ssd, и меня встречают эти два окна со скринов выше. Сначала оно пробует подключиться к серверу Майкрософт, не выходит, и оно пишет про ошибку на скрине 2.

Comment: Попробуйте создать flash drive образ с помощью родной утилиты для HP - https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06162205

Comment: Так тепреь же Microsoft сказала нам good bye. Ставьте линукс

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с подобной ситуацией, аналогично перепробовав 3 сборки вин10, ничего не помогло.
После решил залезть в биос и выключить все пункты безопастности (secure boot и tpm), после сих манипуляций ноутбук без проблем продолжил установку и винда дала создать локального пользователя без интернета.
ПС ноутбук HP на i3 11го поколения, и тоже европеец.

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/843441)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ для тех кто будет в будущем иметь подобную проблему.
После долгих поисков я выяснил в чем проблема с моим ноутбуком. Есть такая штука, называется Microsoft Intune, используется для корпоративных ноутбуков. Суть следующая, привязка к серверам Майкрософта ставится на уровне железа, не поможет ни форматирование жёсткого диска, ни прошивка биоса. Идентификаторы железа которые подключены к материнке, в совокупности зашиваются под конкретную организацию. И какую бы ось я не ставил, мой ноутбук все равно будет пытаться отстучать той организации при первом подключении к интернету.

Есть вариант, вытащить жёсткий диск, подключить к другому ноутбуку и поставить винду там, потом жёсткий диск вернуть на место. Такой вариант поможет. Но нужно так же иметь ввиду, что этото сервис Microsoft Intune не просто позволяет отстучать ноутбуку на сервера, он даёт возможность удалённого доступа. Выходит ноутбук принадлежал какой-то организации, они его не отвязали от этой службы, и теперь они всегда могут удалённо стереть всю информацию с моего компьютера или форматнуть всё полностью. Это будет происходить на уровне железа и ничего сделать нельзя, либо обращаться к компании чтобы отвязала ноутбук, либо, если этой компании уже даже не существует, менять железо, но проще тогда купить новый ноут чем менять всё железо, ведь материнка тоже привязана.
Кому интересно, почитайте подробней что такое Microsoft Intune и поймете почему может быть залочен биос и проблемы с установкой винды.